# tensorflow GAN, 'is_train=False' or 'opt.minimize(var_list=specific_vars)'?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm working on GAN based on DCGAN.

I heard that Generator and Discriminator need to freeze its variable while another is training.

So I did in this way before.

```
G             = generator(batch_size, z, in_h)
D, D_logits   = discriminator(X)
D_, D_logits_ = discriminator(G, reuse=True)

# Variable Grouping
t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
d_var = [var for var in t_vars if 'discriminator' in var.name]
g_var = [var for var in t_vars if 'generator' in var.name]

op_D = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate_D, 
                          beta1=beta1).minimize(D_loss, var_list=d_var)
op_G = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate_G, 
                          beta1=beta1).minimize(G_loss, var_list=g_var)
```

And this is my model

```
def generator(batch_size, z, im_size, is_train=True):
with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=not is_train):

    alpha = 0.2
    #half_size, quat_size = im_size//2, im_size//4

    x1 = tf.layers.dense(z, 4*4*1024)

    x1 = tf.reshape(x1, (-1, 4, 4, 1024))
    x1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x1, training=is_train)
    x1 = tf.maximum(alpha*x1, x1) # leaky relu
    # 4*4*256 now

    x2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x1, 512, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    x2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x2, training=is_train)
    x2 = tf.maximum(alpha*x2, x2)
    # 8*8*512 now

    x3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x2, 256, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    x3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x3, training=is_train)
    x3 = tf.maximum(alpha*x3, x3)
    # 16*16*256 now

    x4 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x3, 128, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    x4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x4, training=is_train)
    x4 = tf.maximum(alpha*x4, x4)
    # 32*32*128 now

    logits = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x4, in_ch, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, (batch_size, im_size, im_size, in_ch))
    # 64*64*3 now

    out = tf.tanh(logits)

    return out


def discriminator(image, reuse=False, is_train=True):
with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):

    alpha = 0.2
    dr_rate = 0.3
    #input 64*64*3

    x1 = tf.layers.conv2d(image, 64, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    x1 = tf.maximum(alpha*x1, x1)
    x1 = tf.layers.dropout(x1, rate=dr_rate, training=is_train)
    # now 32*32*64

    x2 = tf.layers.conv2d(x1, 128, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    x2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x2, training=is_train)
    x2 = tf.maximum(alpha*x2, x2)
    x2 = tf.layers.dropout(x2, rate=dr_rate, training=is_train)
    # now 16*16*128

    x3 = tf.layers.conv2d(x2, 256, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    x3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x3, training=is_train)
    x3 = tf.maximum(alpha*x3, x3)
    x3 = tf.layers.dropout(x3, rate=dr_rate, training=is_train)
    # now 8*8*256

    x4 = tf.layers.conv2d(x3, 512, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
    x4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x4, training=is_train)
    x4 = tf.maximum(alpha*x4, x4)
    x4 = tf.layers.dropout(x4, rate=dr_rate, training=is_train)
    # now 4*4*512

    flat = tf.reshape(x4, (-1, 4*4*512))
    logits = tf.layers.dense(flat, 1)
    out = tf.sigmoid(logits)

    return out, logits
```

please ignore indentations of scope.

if I make second discriminator's is_train=False, result changes.

```
D_, D_logits_ = discriminator(G, reuse=True, is_train=False)
```

like this. it seems G cannot learn well after changing is_train=False.

Anyone know why is it? I think this code only optimize 'g_var' during op_G,

so changing of discriminator's 'is_train' should not effect the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the second version of the discriminator be trainable is essential for GANs to work properly. If the discriminator is not able to update its weights based on the output of the generator, it will never learn to distinguish real from fake, so it will never provide meaningful feedback for the generator to learn. By setting the second copy of the discriminator to not be trainable, you are trying to train classifier on a two-class problem by only showing it one of the classes.

For reference, you can see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/train.py#L103) how TensorFlow's TFGAN library sets up the generator/discriminator networks.